# Interspire shopping cart - Custom variables?

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I'm trying to add some custom variables which can be accessed in the templates using Interspire. I'm not sure how to do this without touching the core. Anybody know the best practices for this?

Answer (score 0):

Which custom variables are you trying to add? I am pretty sure you will have to "touch the core" if you want to make significant changes to the template...